# BasemapGallery loading event

Tags: arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can we find the event when basemapGallery is completely loaded in ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.4 ?

When try to find the items in basemapGallery view model, it is taking sometime to get it loaded, currently am achieving it through  setTimeout method.

Answer (score 2):

This [blog post](http://odoe.net/blog/quick-tip-arcgis-api-4-js-stuff-ready/) by Rene Rubalcava is a good overview on how to find out when you have access to layers and when data is visible on the screen. It goes over how to use the MapView [updating](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#updating) property and the LayerView [updating](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-LayerView.html#updating) property to get notification of the various stages of updating.